# My IP was changed - without connecting to another network. How can I go back to the old one?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ip

OK. Seems like my IP address was changed. That's nothing weird, but I just don't know why it changed, since I didn't switched to another network. I am still using my old home network. How can I go back to the old IP? Moreover, the network is much more slower than before.

---

P.S.: I used VPNs, but they are turned off.

Comment: Setup fix ip in your router. Or if you talk about your public/external ip, then ask your isp!

Comment: Are you referring to your public or private IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a private IP, check if your old IP is not in use (ping towards it or use more advanced detection).
If it's not allocated, put it as static. Check the rest of the network settings on the current one so you set them exactly the same when you use the static one.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that you are talking about your private IP address, it seems that your DHCP (more information in [RFC 2132](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2132.txt)) lease time has expired. If you only can connect to your network with DHCP, then you cannot do anything in order to go back to your old IP.

From RFC 2132:

> 9.2. IP Address Lease Time
>
> This option is used in a client request (DHCPDISCOVER or
>   DHCPREQUEST)    to allow the client to request a lease time for the IP
>   address.  In a    server reply (DHCPOFFER), a DHCP server uses this
>   option to specify    the lease time it is willing to offer.